# Asynchronous vs Synchronous Webservice Calls

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to clear up what it means to be a asynchronous/synchronous and blocking/non-blocking operations in Scala Play using Scala's Future.

So we can have:

1. Asynchronous and non-blocking
2. Asynchronous and blocking
3. Synchronous and non-blocking
4. Synchronous and blocking

In the Play documentation it says that all operations are asynchronous. But I would like to know how the following would be classed:

If I call an external web service and I have to wait for the response then is this considered to be a asynchronous and blocking operation? For example:

```scala
def externalWebCall(url : String): Future[SomeData]
def storeData(data : String) : Future[Unit]

for {
data <- externalWebCall(url)
_    <- storeData(data)
} yield(data)
```

In this example, I don't want storeData to execute until the externalWebCall service has completed. Is the above code the right way to achieve this? If so I think this is asynchronous and blocking.

The initial request that comes to Play service is treated in an asynchronous and non-blocking way according to the documentation. My understanding of this is that when the Play server receives the request it will not block the main thread. It will then service the request and then make a call to the callback of this request and then return the result. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

When people use the term "asynchronous", they usually mean "non-blocking", in the sense that the current execution thread will not stop and wait for the result. In general, synchronous means blocking, asynchronous means non-blocking.

It seems you are confusing "blocking" with "ordering the execution". Your example with the `Futures` is completely asynchronous, and it equivalent to

```
val result: Future[Unit] = externalWebCall(url).flatMap(storeData)
```

`storeData` can only execute when `externalWebCall` is done, but any code that would come after `val result = ...` could also execute before either `externalWebCall` or `storeData`. The execution of these methods is wrapped in a `Future` and run in a different thread, so you have no way of knowing when it will happen. That is what asynchronous means.

Answer (score 1):

The terms **blocking** and **asynchronous** have different meanings, but are often confused or used interchangeably.

**blocking** means that the current thread waits for another thread to do something before executing further instructions. The current thread is **blocked** until the other thread completes and then it can continue.

**asynchronous** means that an operation happens on another thread while the current thread continues to execute. The current thread **initiates** an operation but then continues to execute. When the asynchronous operation completes it notifies the current thread by raising an **event** or calling some **event handler** function.

Blocking functions look like normal functions and there is not necessarily any indication that the code being called is blocking or non blocking. So a `println` statement may be blocking for `stderr` but non-blocking for `stdout`.

Asynchronous functions will always have a mechanism for being notified of completion of the operation and this will be visible in the interface. In Scala this usually means returning `Future[T]` rather than `T`.

---

In your example, both `externalWebCall` and `storeData` are *asynchronous* because each method returns `Future`.

`storeData` takes a `data` argument that is only available when `externalWebCall` completes, so these two operations must by definition operate sequentially.